# Find the updated fields on update request

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a user entity as

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String address;

  // getter / setter

}
```

And controller method like:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/user")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {

 userRepository.save(user);

   // ...
}
```

Now What I am trying to do is finding the field that is being updated.
Example:
If the only name is present I need some message like "Updated field is name".
Is there any better way other than comparing the fields one by one with the database stored values.

Answer (score 0):

you need getUser method. for example: userRepository.getUser(user.id)
then you return the result

Comment: Yes, It will give me the un-updated data. But I was looking for some other efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: @SudipBolakhe, actually, you dont need call repository to get updated user. you already have the updated user in the parameter. just return that

Comment: @Tarul My requirement is to find Are all the fields updated or only some?